# Create a table like file from a key - value log file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a log file like this

```
27/12/2020 00:05:30,848 ===== Request ======
code = 0
trigger1 = false
trigger2 = false
field = {
     1|status=0
     2|tag=abcdef
     3|price=35
     ...
}
===== Response =====
code = 1
trigger1 = false
trigger2 = false
field = {
     5|id=123
     1|status=404
     2|tag=ghijkl
     4|barcode=26121111
     3|price=35
     ...
}
27/12/2020 00:10:35,941 ===== Request ======
code = 0
trigger1 = false
trigger2 = false
field = {
     1|status=0
     2|tag=abcdef
     3|price=35
     ...
}
===== Response =====
code = 1
trigger1 = false
trigger2 = false
field = {
     5|id=123
     1|status=404
     2|tag=ghijkl
     4|barcode=26121111
     3|price=35
     ...
}
```

The `...` represent for all the not so useful field.
I want to create a table like this (or csv file is good too):

```
Time                     id   status tag    price barcode
27/12/2020 00:05:30,848  Null 0      abcdef 35    Null
27/12/2020 00:05:30,848  123  404    ghijkl 35    26121111
27/12/2020 00:10:35,941  Null 0      abcdef 35    Null
27/12/2020 00:10:35,941  123  404    ghijkl 35    26121111
```

I have used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35460169) but it's not working good :(
Now I'm temporary use `grep` to add status, tag and price and `paste` them to a single file because it's got the same number of output but id and barcode is not.
My code is somewhat like this:

```
grep "1|status=" file > status
grep "2|tag=" file > tag
grep "3|price=" file > price
paste status tag price > output
```

My output file look like this

```
1|status=0   2|tag=abcdef  3|price=35
1|status=404 2|tag=ghijkl  3|price=35
1|status=0   2|tag=abcdef  3|price=35
1|status=404 2|tag=ghijkl  3|price=35
```

I want to grep in each `field = { * }` and see if it's have all the key-value, if not return null. I'm very new to bash scripting so I don't really know if my way to solve it is optimize or not. I need help from you guys.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you @thanasisp I have just edited the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    numTags = split("Time id status tag price barcode",tags)
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
/= Request =/ {
    time = substr($0,1,23)
}
sub(/^[[:space:]]*([0-9]+\|)?/,"") {
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^=]+=[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
}
/^}/ {
    tag2val["Time"] = time
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = (tag in tag2val ? tag2val[tag] : "Null")
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete tag2val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
Time                     id    status  tag     price  barcode
27/12/2020 00:05:30,848  Null  0       abcdef  35     Null
27/12/2020 00:05:30,848  123   404     ghijkl  35     26121111
27/12/2020 00:10:35,941  Null  0       abcdef  35     Null
27/12/2020 00:10:35,941  123   404     ghijkl  35     26121111
```

Comment: The script works incredible well. Thank you so much!!! Now I'm running this line by line to truly understand it. Thank again ^^